# Passport SerializeUser being called multiple times

Tags: node.js, passport.js

My understanding on how the Node passport session middleware works is that SerializeUser is called once to setup the cookie, it stores the session id in the cookie, and user details in the session.  On subsequent invocation it uses the cookie to extract the session and then calls deserialize user.  So the expected sequence would be 
SerializeUser
DeserializeUser
DeserializeUser ( and so on , until the session times out )

However I am getting a serializeUser call interspersed between every 2 deserialize calls.  I captured the stack and it shows as follows;

DeserializeUser:

```
at /server/src/utils/passport.js:82:3
at pass (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:357:9)
at Authenticator.deserializeUser (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:362:5)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:60:10)
at attempt (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:361:16)
at authenticate (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:362:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

SerializeUser:

```
at pass (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:294:9)
at Authenticator.serializeUser (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:299:5)
at SessionManager.logIn (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/sessionmanager.js:14:8)
at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:50:33)
at FacebookTokenStrategy.strategy.success (/server/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:248:13)
at verified (/server/node_modules/passport-facebook-token/lib/index.js:102:25)
at FacebookTokenStrategy._verify (/server/src/utils/passport.js:64:7)
at <anonymous>
```

If there are any pointers why this might be so?  I seem to be losing any benefits of the session if it continues to authenticate.

I have been researching this further. When we ask for authenticate, passport cycles through its strategies.  Each strategy can either respond one of the following: success, fail, pass or error.  If its success, it won't try the next strategy. This issue here is that the Session Strategy responds with pass even though it was able to successfully serialize.  The passport authenticator then attempts to do the next strategy which is the facebook auth, which causes SerializeUser to happen.  I fail to understand why the SessionStrategy did not immediately respond with Success and stop passport from exploring the following strategies.